# Is there any difference between $.trim and trim?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple example below which uses trim. As per the title of the question, is there any difference between them?. As you can see below they have the same output. If the answer is "No", which one is much better to use?

Currently I use `.trim()` because it's my first time seeing `$.trim()`.

```js
var SampleTrim = '     TRIM         ';

console.log(SampleTrim.trim());
console.log($.trim(SampleTrim));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can refer https://jsperf.com/jquery-trim-vs-string-prototype-trim/11 for performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.prototype.trim` is not available below IE9, otherwise they are the same.

The recommended `String.prototype.trim` [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill) on MDN is exactly the same as that used in jQuery [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ac9e3016645078e1e42120822cfb2076151c8cbe/src/core.js#L39).

In most cases, the **native implementation** would be faster to use. This [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/jquery-trim-vs-string-prototype-trim/11) by [Sumit Gulati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458540/sumit-gulati) suggests that too.

Realistically, the difference in performance would be quite negligible and I wouldn't base my decision on performance. However, it would be better to use the native implementation so that there's no dependency on jQuery. The large websites have dropped support for IE8 and I think it's safe to follow suit (:

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [`trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function was available long before JavaScript's native [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function was added, which is available in browsers above IE9 and the like.

Use the native trim function for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, SimpleTrim.trim() is a native way to trim a string that modern brower support.

And $.trim(SimpleTrim) is another way that jQuery help user in the past to trim string, when browser does not support native trim.